# LEFT JOIN to display records not in Right table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables ECRDTL_del and ECRDTL_edit, I want to display only records from ECRDTL_del which are not in ECRDTL_edit.
I have tried using MYSQL left join, but unable to get the desired result. Here is my current querystring:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM ECRDTL_del AS a
    LEFT JOIN ECRDTL_edit AS b ON b.Ecrno = a.Ecrno
WHERE b.Cylno <> a.Cylno
```

Data Example of both the tables and expected result out of these two mentioned below:

ECRDTL_del:

```
Ecrno  Cylno
9090   8881
9090   8882
9090   8883
9090   8884
```

ECRDTL_edit:

```
Ecrno  Cylno
9090   8881
9090   8885
9090   8886
9090   8884
```

Result expected after LEFT join:

```
Ecrno  Cylno
9090   8882
9090   8883
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your question:

> "...I want to display only records from ECRDTL_del which are not in ECRDTL_edit."

You are close, you just need to check if `b.Ecrno IS NULL`.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   ECRDTL_del AS a 
       LEFT JOIN ECRDTL_edit AS b 
          ON a.Ecrno = b.Ecrno AND 
             a.Cylno = b.Cylno
WHERE  b.Ecrno IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54abb/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ ECRNO ║ CYLNO ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║  9090 ║  8882 ║
║  9090 ║  8883 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: This sql statement is giving error on MYSQL, Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from ECRDTL_editSELECT a.* FROM ECRDTL_del AS a LEFT JOIN EC' at line 3

Comment: what is the syntax you are executing? See the Sqlfiddle Demo, it is fully working there.

Comment: I saw in SQLFiddle, it is working fine. But not sure why it is not working on my server - MYSQL - Phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use `EXISTS` for this type of thing:

```
SELECT *
FROM ECRDTL_del as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM ECRDTL_edit as b
    WHERE b.Ecrno = a.Ecrno
    AND b.Cylno = a.Cylno
)
```

The minute it finds a matching record, it will stop, whereas something like an `IN` will continue to search for matching records.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from ECRDTL_del where Cylno not in (select Cylno from ECRDTL_edit)
```

Comment: this will not work at all time if you want to check a group of `Ecrno`.